# Set the selected value of a multi-select drop down in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, multi-select

I have a multi-select dropdown in my view and I would like to show the selected item of the dropdown which has been selected and submitted already. This is the html code.

```
               <label>Submitter</label><br />
                <select id="SelectedSubmitterIDs" name="SelectedSubmitterIDs" class="SubmitterIDClass" multiple>
                    @foreach (var data in Model.Submitters)
                    {
                        <option value="@data.Value">@data.Text</option>
                    }
                </select>
```

I am using the jquery multi-select library to achieve multiple selections in the dropdown. I would like to view the selected values on READ operation.

```
$('#SelectedSubmitterIDs').multiselect({
    selectAllText: ' Select all',
    enableFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '200px',
    maxHeight: 200,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, tweaking the  to Html razor Listbox worked for me - 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1778536.aspx?Loading+Multiselect+Listboxfor+in+MVC3+Razor

```
 <label>Submitter</label><br />
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSubmitterIDs, new MultiSelectList(Model.Submitters, "Value", "Text"), new { @multiple = "multiple" })
```

These dropdowns are showing the selected values from their respective data source - e.g. Model.Submitters. Hope this helps someone else facing a similar scenario. Thanks

[image: multiple select]